# how to add dataset values to sql

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, dataset

I am new to SQL (started today itself), how to add data of dataset to the database table when the table in database has the first column as automatic generating numbers i.e., (IDENTITY (1,1))

I have DataSet something like this

```
  name    age    location

   x      30       yyy
   y      20       ppp
```

The table in Database is something like this

```
  Id(auto)   name    age    location

  --------  no data  --------------
```

First of all I am filling the Dataset from the database table.
Since the first column is autogenerated I cant even add new values to DataSet.
If I say

```
 dsMainDoctors.Tables[0].Rows.Add( /* first column is autogenerated so I am leaving it*/
                secondColumn,
                thirdColumn,
                fourthColumn,
                FifthColumn);
```

Error --> Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store  in Doctor_ID Column.  Expected type is Int32.

The code I am trying is: (*When I given the first column value manually in the DataSet*)

```
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        conn.Open();
        da.Update(ds.Tables[0]);  //ERROR :- Update requires a valid InsertCommand when passed DataRow collection with new rows.
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
        cmd.Dispose();
```

---

```
 strQuery --> "delete from [dbo].[" + table_name + "]";
```

I could have searched this before asking but I dont know what keywords I should use
Please answer in comments if it is very easy question.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Where are you constructing the `DataSet` and `DataTable`? Is it a typed `DataSet` you built through the designer?

Comment: It is not typed dataset. I will post the code too wait

Comment: @BigM I updated my question. please check once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the following code will build that INSERT command properly for you. Also, please note, that if you're concerned about disposing objects, use the `using` statement instead because it will call `Dispose` when exiting the statement.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, conn);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

using (cmd)
{
    using (conn)
    {
        conn.Open();

        da.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand();
        da.Update(ds.Tables[0]);  //ERROR :- Update requires a valid InsertCommand when passed DataRow collection with new rows.

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

### EDIT

If you're just wanting to `delete` the data in the database to rebuild it then that's quite different than what you're original question was implying. However, below is how simple that would be.

```
var strQuery = "delete from [dbo].[" + table_name + "]";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, conn);
var rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

// do something with rowsAffected if you want

// now you can build `insert` statements if you want
// to put more data into it, which you could use the
// previous example for that
```

Comment: Thank you for response, VS showing red scribbles to "adapter" saying "the name 'adapter' doesnot exist in the current context" what should I keep instead of it here. I replace it with `da` then it showing error `Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any base table information.`

Comment: Okay, the `adapter` problem was just a typo. However, the other error you're getting suggests that the `SELECT` query is odd. **Edit your question with the value that is in `strQuery` please.**

Comment: strQuery has `"delete from [dbo].[" + table_name + "]"`  (passing through method) table_name is string

Comment: That statement needs to be `"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[" + table_name + "]"`. The `SqlDataAdapter` constructor is expecting a `select` command. Please reference the documentation on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awzk4kc1.aspx.

Comment: But I want to delete the data in the database table and fill again with the dataset. how can I do this?

Comment: @Mr_Green, great! I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Comment: I dont want to ask a new question which could be headache for others too.. As you can understand here that I am filling database table from dataset on a Button click. When User press again the Button I want to show a message that "no changes made to dataset after saving". How to do this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18966/discussion-between-bigm-and-mr-green)

Answer (score 1):

In order to update a table with result of `DataTable` you must have to configure `SelectCommand`, `DeleteCommand`, `InsertCommand` and `UpdateCommand` properties (SqlCommand object) of [SqlDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx) class.